# Logstash No config files found in path

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am getting following exception when start Logstash on my Windows10 machine.

```
Sending Logstash logs to D:/elk/logstash-7.7.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-06-15T23:37:21,547][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-06-15T23:37:21,669][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.7.1"}
[2020-06-15T23:37:22,275][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"D:/elk/logstash-7.7.1/bin/logstash.config"}
[2020-06-15T23:37:22,304][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
[2020-06-15T23:37:22,668][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-06-15T23:37:27,569][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

My `Logstash.config`

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => "test"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index  => "app1-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I saved this `logstash.config` under `bin` folder of the logstash and following command used to start Logstash server `logstash.bat -f logstash.config`
Apart from this config file I didn't changed anything. How can I resolve this error? Do I need to configure anything else?
Please help me on this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I placed my logstash.config file to outside of the Logstash folder, its works fine.